# Angular minimize redundant calls

Tags: angular, angularjs, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, redundancy

Currently have a component thats calling the api call in a multiple places and its showing in the network tab when the page loads. Is there a way to use ngrx/store to minimize the redundant calls? Its getting different data each time its being called. Not sure if theres way to minimize that? Using angular 10.

```
/app-config different params
/app-config different params
/app-config different params
/app-config different params
```

a way to show it in the network tab once instead of 4 times

Comment: Where are the api calls being made in your application?

Comment: @laudebugs in the component ngOninit

Comment: component is huge and i have calls happening in child components too

Comment: You should add to the question the relevant parts of code where these calls are made, it is almost impossible to answer you without additional infos. Also from "Its getting different data each time its being called" -> if the data is different, aren't those calls not redundant? Additionnally, you can debug the call stack of these functions with a "console.error" just before the call to see in the developper tools which functions originally called your code

Comment: @Kaddath i have a couple of calls calling the same endpoint then doing something different with the data. Was just thinking of having an ngrx component state management that would call the api once and then create getters that would just get the data from state and whatever i want with it

Comment: there isnt any prams, i put it up there as a mistake

Comment: just the same call happening a couple of times

Comment: This is too vague for us to answer you, a code sample is worth a thousands explanations, there could be things in the code you overlooked that cause your problems, etc